# Webpack creates unnecessary .js file for my CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, webpack

I have this Webpack config for compiling CSS, JavaScript and HTML

```
{
  entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, 'clientside', 'client.js')],
    styles: path.join(__dirname, 'clientside', 'styles.css')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module:
  {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: { presets:['es2015', 'stage-0'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'clientside/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['main'],
      minify: htmlMinifierObj
    })
  ],
}
```

The problem with this config is it creates an unnecessary `styles.js` file, I don't need it.

I also know I can include styles.css inside my JS file but I don't think it's a good idea, because I want to keep JavaScript and CSS separated.

So, my question is: how can I edit my config to get rid of this unnecessary file?

Comment: I think if you remove the `styles` from your entry and `require('styles.css')` inside your javascript, that will properly extract the text into an external file.

Comment: @BenNyberg I know, I mentioned this in my question but the thing is I want to keep JavaScript and CSS separated. Is there another way?

Comment: Well, depends on what you mean. The extract text plugin will pull the styles out into a separate css file during your build process, so you will end up with separated JS and CSS files. Your javascript will reference your css file, but they are still separated.